# Remove numbers in a word using php

Tags: php

I have a string that is returned from an API. For some reason one of the values within the JSON returned is null54 which breaks the json_decode and therefore doesn't allow me to access it as an array correctly.

Example String: `{"ttl": null54 "card_id": "np"}.DPTQIg.eeQ-wZYaH8ptEofYGZM0E8ICZDQ`

You will see this has `null54` as a value for `ttl`. This prevents the below PHP from working. If I manually remove `54` then the php works fine. How can I remove any numbers that may be with `null` to prevent the php from not working? I cannot guarantee that it will always be 54 either.

Working PHP:

```
$string = '{"ttl": null, "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg';
$string = explode('}', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0] .'}');
echo $json->card_id;
```

Non-Working PHP:

```
$string = '{"ttl": null54, "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg';
$string = explode('}', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0] .'}');
echo $json->card_id;
```

Comment: Just to approach from a different direction (and I'm not sure if this is viable in your case), can you raise a bug on the API?

Comment: Yeah, I'd be complaining to the folks providing the API. That looks like someone clearly copy/pasted some variable where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I have done this however they have no intention of fixing this soon and so I need to try and find a way round it for now. Frustrating!

Comment: You should look into `preg_replace`. Your `explode` approach is going to... *explode* if there's ever a second level of data in the JSON, like `{"ttl": null, "card_id": "np", "user": {"id": 1}}`.

Comment: I've had confirmation that this format won't change so I am taking a chance on that bit for atleast now

Comment: @BenH Good luck! Sorry you're working with lunatics on the other end. :-p

Comment: haha thanks! We will get it sorted, just a matter of when!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a bug with the API, and @chris-forrence is correct in that you should raise a bug with the API maintainer if possible... That being said, you'll probably have to work around the issue, at least for a while.

I think the easiest way to do this would be using a regexp find and replace. This can be handled with the `preg_replace()` function and would look something like:

```php
$string = preg_replace('/null[0-9]+/', 'null', $string)
```

Here the first argument is a regex, that matches the string 'null' and any number of digits following it.

Comment: Side note: Whatever solution you pick, OP, *make sure it works when the bug is fixed too*.

Comment: Thank you @Jacobm001 I will try this out. I have raised the bug with the API team today but need a work around in the meantime. As ceejayoz mentioned I will have to make sure this works with or without numbers within null